# Update the Unique number for the co-related records between two columns in the group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to identify and update co-related records associated rank under Req_Result column as depicted below. 
Table name is tblSource.

```html
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| Item | key | DenseRankWrtKey | Req_Res |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| a    | 1   | 1               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| a    | 2   | 2               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| a    | 3   | 3               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| b    | 2   | 2               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| b    | 9   | 7               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| c    | 1   | 1               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| c    | 6   | 5               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| d    | 5   | 4               | 4       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| e    | 8   | 6               | 6       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| f    | 2   | 2               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
| f    | 6   | 5               | 1       |
+------+-----+-----------------+---------+
```

**Item** and **Key** are **co-related columns** and DenseRankWrtKey is created by using Dense rank with respect to key. I need to assign the same DenseRankWrtKey values to all the co-related values.

**Scenario explained:**

**Item** a has the **key** value **1** and **1** is co-related with **c** as well, so all related values for **a** and **1** are **a,b,c,f,2,3,7,6,5** hence all these values are assigned as **1** by referring **DenseRank** column, **d** and **e** are not further related to any other values hence its value is kept as is from **DenseRank** column.

I tried the queries

```
Update a 
SET a.Req_Res = b.DenseRankWrtKey 
from tblSource a 
inner join tblSource b on a.DenseRankWrtKey = b.DenseRankWrtKey
```

which is not sufficient.

**Just try for this table too :** `DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Item varchar(100)
    ,[key] INT
    ,DenseRankWrtKey INT
    ,Req_Res INT
)
INSERT INTO @Table
(
    Item
    ,[key]
    ,DenseRankWrtKey
)
VALUES
('p', 10 ,1 ),
('q', 10 ,1 ),
('r', 20 ,2 ),
('s', 30 ,3 ),
('t', 30 ,3 ),
('u', 40 ,4 ),
('v', 40 ,4 ),
('w', 40 ,4 ),
('p', 50 ,5 ),
('q', 50 ,5 ),
('r', 50 ,5 ),
('s', 50 ,5 ),
('t', 50 ,5 ),
('u', 50 ,5 ),
('v', 50 ,5 ),
('w', 50 ,5 )`

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Your second set of data, for instance, has not intended results.  And it has no repeated items, which I *think* is important to the question, so it is odd that sample data doesn't have any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this way easier to read and maintain

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Item CHAR(1), ItemKey INT, DenseRankWrtKey INT, Req_Res INT)

INSERT @TestTable (Item, ItemKey, DenseRankWrtKey) VALUES 
('a'    , 1   , 1)
, ('a'    , 2   , 2)
, ('a'    , 3   , 3)
, ('b'    , 2   , 2)
, ('b'    , 9   , 7)
, ('c'    , 1   , 1)
, ('c'    , 6   , 5)
, ('d'    , 5   , 4)
, ('e'    , 8   , 6)
, ('f'    , 2   , 2)
, ('f'    , 6   , 5)

DECLARE @OtpTable TABLE (Item CHAR(1), ItemKey INT, DenseRankWrtKey INT)

DECLARE @RC INT = 1

WHILE @RC > 0
BEGIN

    DELETE @OtpTable

    ;WITH UpdateCTE AS (
      SELECT TOP 1  * from @TestTable 
      WHERE Req_Res IS NULL
    )
    UPDATE UpdateCTE 
    set Req_Res = DenseRankWrtKey
    OUTPUT Inserted.Item, Inserted.ItemKey, inserted.DenseRankWrtKey INTO @OtpTable

    SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT

    WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    UPDATE T
    SET Req_Res = (SELECT TOP 1 DenseRankWrtKey FROM @OtpTable)
    OUTPUT Inserted.Item, Inserted.ItemKey, inserted.DenseRankWrtKey INTO @OtpTable
    FROM @TestTable T
    WHERE T.Req_Res IS NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @OtpTable OT WHERE (T.Item = OT.Item OR T.ItemKey = OT.ItemKey))

END

SELECT * FROM @TestTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do update in single statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(
    Id INT 
    ,Item varchar(30)
    ,[key] INT
    ,DenseRankWrtKey INT
    ,Req_Res INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table
(
    Item
    ,[key]
    ,DenseRankWrtKey
)
VALUES
<YOUR DATA>


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Item
        ,T.[Key]
        ,Id = RANK() OVER(order by T.DenseRankWrtKey,T.Item)
    FROM 
        #Table AS T
)
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.Id = CTE.Id
FROM
    CTE 
    INNER JOIN #Table AS T ON T.Item = CTE.Item AND T.[key] = CTE.[key]

DECLARE @LoopVal INT = 0
        ,@LoopReq INT = NULL
        ,@LoopKey VARCHAR(50) = NULL

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1
        @LoopVal = T.DenseRankWrtKey
        ,@LoopReq = T.Req_Res
    FROM
        #Table AS T
    WHERE
        T.DenseRankWrtKey > @LoopVal
    ORDER BY
        T.DenseRankWrtKey ASC

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;

    UPDATE T2
    SET Req_Res = CASE WHEN @LoopReq IS NOT NULL THEN @LoopReq ELSE T.DenseRankWrtKey END
    FROM 
        #Table AS T
        INNER JOIN #Table AS T2 ON T.[key] = T2.[key]
    WHERE
        T.DenseRankWrtKey = @LoopVal
        AND T2.Req_Res IS NULL

    UPDATE
        T
    SET
        T.Req_Res = CASE WHEN @LoopReq IS NOT NULL THEN @LoopReq ELSE T2.Req_Res END 
    FROM 
        #Table AS T
        INNER JOIN #Table AS T2 ON T.Item = T2.Item
                                    AND T2.Req_Res IS NOT NULL
                                    AND T.Req_Res IS NULL

END
SELECT * FROM #Table
ORDER BY
    DenseRankWrtKey
DROP TABLE #Table
GO
```

Comment: For larger tables, it is giving wrong results. and id is not required

Comment: ID has been added just for the looping purpose. You can use any existing unique column for that. For the larger tables can you share some more data.

Comment: Thanks Akash, Just also check for the edited question table which i am finding difficult to get answer now

Comment: Same logic will work. I have just added ORDER BY T.Item. Please check the updated answer...

Comment: if i add this code then other results are getting nullified